# Get InnerText from Collection

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, innertext

Is there a way to get the innertext of a node when the node is inside a collection
Currently i have this

```
Collection<string> DependentNodes = new Collection<string>();
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
  {
    DependentNodes.Add(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerXml);
    //the reason i'm using InnerXml is that it will return all the child node of  testfixture in one single line,then we can find the category & check if there's dependson
   }
}
    string selectedtestcase = "abc_somewords";
    foreach (string s in DependentNodes)
     {
      if(s.Contains(selectedtestcase))
       {
        MessageBox.Show("aaa");
       }

     }
```

When i debug string s or the index has this inside of it[in a single line]

```
<testfixture name="1" description="a">
  <categories>
    <category>abc_somewords</category>
  </categories>
  <test name="a" description="a">
    <dependencies>
      <dependson typename="dependsonthis" />
    </dependencies>
  </test>
</testfixture>
```

What i'm trying to do is when we reach "testfixture 1" it will find "abc_somewords" & search the "dependson typename"node(if any) and get the "typename"(which is "dependonthis").

Comment: what type is `DependentNodes`?

Comment: Dependentnode is a collection

Comment: Sorry never use Linq before, how would we use it?

Comment: You can try @Jason's answer, if linq is not your option.

Comment: I have updated my answer now to match the new xml data as well as ensuring only the values of the typename attribute are extracted where the category matches your text.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use linq to xml.  Something like the below might be a decent start

```
xml.Elements("categories").Where(x => x.Element("category").Value.Contains(selectedtestcase));
```

This is off the top of my head so might will need refining

P.S. Use XElement.Load or XElement.Parse to get your xml into XElements

Comment: The above will return the parent node so once he has these he can use the same technique to get the test node

Answer (score 3):

Since you already working with `XmlNode` you could use a XPath expression to select the desired `textfixture` node, and select the dependency value:

```
XmlDocument doc = // ...
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//testfixture[contains(categories/category, \"abc\")]/test/dependencies/dependson/");

if (node != null)
{
  MessageBox.Show(node.Attributes["typename"]);
}
```

This selects the `dependson` node which belongs to a `testfixture` node with a `category` containing "abc". `node.Attributes["typename"]` will return the value of the `typename` attribute.

**Edited:**
Updated XPath expression to the more specific question information

Answer (score 3):

> **Assumptions**

As you are looping in your code and wanting to create a collection I'm assuming the actual Xml File has several `testfixture` nodes inside such as the below assumed example:

```
<root>
  <testfixture name="1" description="a">
    <categories>
      <category>abc_somewords</category>
    </categories>
    <test name="a" description="a">
      <dependencies>
        <dependson typename="dependsonthis" />
      </dependencies>
    </test>
  </testfixture>
  <testfixture name="2" description="a">
    <categories>
      <category>another_value</category>
    </categories>
    <test name="b" description="a">
      <dependencies>
        <dependson typename="secondentry" />
      </dependencies>
    </test>
  </testfixture>
  <testfixture name="3" description="a">
    <categories>
      <category>abc_somewords</category>
    </categories>
    <test name="c" description="a">
      <dependencies>
        <dependson typename="thirdentry" />
      </dependencies>
    </test>
  </testfixture>
</root>
```

> **The Code using Linq to Xml**

To use Linq you must reference the following name spaces:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Using Linq To Xml on the above assumed xml file structure would look like this:

```
// To Load Xml Content from File.
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\MyXml.xml");

Collection<string> DependentNodes = new Collection<string>();

var results =
    doc1.Root.Elements("testfixture")
    .Where(x => x.Element("categories").Element("category").Value.Contains("abc_somewords"))
    .Elements("test").Elements("dependencies").Elements("dependson").Attributes("typename").ToArray();

foreach (XAttribute attribute in results)
{
    DependentNodes.Add(attribute.Value.Trim());
}
```

> **Result**

The resulting Collection will contain the following:

[image]

As you can see, only the text of the `typename` attribute has been extracted where the `dependson` nodes where in a `testfixture` node which contained a `category` node with the value of `abc_somewords`.

> **Additional Notes**

If you read the xml from a string you can also use this:

```
// To Load Xml Content from a string.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myXml);
```

If your **complete** Xml structure is different, feel free to post it and I change the code to match.

Have Fun.

Comment: I have now updated my code to match the xml file structure. I also have updated the Linq query to extract the dependson attribute typename value as required. Hope this will help you out now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is "nodes" you are using.

Here is code with your requirement(What I understood).

```
Collection<XmlNode> DependentNodes = new Collection<XmlNode>();

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xDoc.Load(@"Path_Of_Your_xml");

        foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("testfixture"))  // Here I am accessing only root node. Give Xpath if ur requrement is changed
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                DependentNodes.Add(node.ChildNodes[i]);
            }
        }
        string selectedtestcase = "abc_somewords";

        foreach (var s in DependentNodes)
        {
            if (s.InnerText.Contains(selectedtestcase))
            {
                Console.Write("aaa");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string XML = "<testfixture name=\"1\" description=\"a\">" +
                             "<categories>" +
                             "<category>abc_somewords</category>" +
                             "</categories>" +
                             "<test name=\"a\" description=\"a\">" +
                             "<dependencies>" +
                             "<dependson typename=\"dependsonthis\" />" +
                             "</dependencies>" +
                             "</test>" +
                             "</testfixture>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(XML);

            var testfixture = document.SelectSingleNode("//testfixture[@name = 1]");

            var category = testfixture.SelectSingleNode(".//category[contains(text(), 'abc_somewords')]");

            if(category != null)
            {
                var depends = testfixture.SelectSingleNode("//dependson");
                Console.Out.WriteLine(depends.Attributes["typename"].Value);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output: dependsonthis